# Salesforce B2B Commerce (LWR) - "global.css" style

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc, b2b, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm quite new to B2B LWR, but I'm not new to web development in general.

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to have like a global.css (general css styles) and then particular css styles at LWC level.

So with B2B Commerce (LWR) I was researching what can be done but I failed to find the correct info on how should I approach this.

I tried to include in the head tag where I have other link tags a reference to a static resource called globalStyles (globalStyles.css)

```
<!-- General -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{basePath}/assets/favicon.ico?{versionKey}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{basePath}/assets/css/font-awesome.css?{versionKey}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{basePath}/assets/css/theme.css?{versionKey}">


<!-- webruntime-branding-shared stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css?{ versionKey }" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/assets/styles/dxp-site-spacing-styling-hooks.min.css?{ versionKey }" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/assets/styles/dxp-styling-hooks.min.css?{ versionKey }" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/assets/styles/dxp-slds-extensions.min.css?{ versionKey }" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/assets/themes/alpine.css?{ versionKey }" />

<!-- HERE IS THE GLOBAL STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(!URLFOR($Resource.globalStyles, 'globalStyles.css'))" />
```

But it seems URLFOR doesn't work, $Resource doesn't work...
Don't exactly know how to reference that static resource file (css)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/{sitebase}/resource/{resourceid}/{resourcename}?{version}">
```

Note: This answer was taken from this, for more detail.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363693/static-resource-stylesheet-in-head-markup-of-experience-builder-site

Doc Reference

[Head Markup doc for LWR Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_differences_markup.htm)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Can you also indicate how do I get the {resourceid}?

Answer (score 0):

In LWR, you can just use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/sfsites/c/resource/stylesheet/globalStyles.css?{ versionKey }" />
```

Check this reference for more details:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_differences_markup.htm